# fullcalendar.io with ionic2

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, ionic2

I'm trying to use fullcalendar.io on my angular2 project, but it simply don't work... Someone can try too and see what I'm doing wrong?

First of all I installed(I already had installed moment an jquery by npm)
npm install fullcalendar

later I installed the typings:
typings install dt~fullcalendar --global --save

In my calendario.html I add the div with id='calendar' .

And on my .ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {CalendarEvent} from '../calendario/calendar-event'
import * as $ from 'jquery'
import * as moment from "moment";

@Component({
templateUrl: 'build/pages/calendario/calendario.html',
})
export class CalendarioPage {

constructor(private navCtrl:NavController) {

}

initiateCalendar(calEvents:CalendarEvent[]):void {
    var calendar: JQuery = $("#calendar");
    calendar.fullCalendar({
        header: {
            left: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay",
            center: "title",
            right: "today prev,next"
        },
        events: calEvents,
        firstDay: 1,
        weekMode: "fluid",
        dayClick: (date:Date, allDay:boolean, jsEvent:Event, view:FullCalendar.ViewObject) => {
            //this.goToDay(calendar, date, view);
        }
    });
}

goToDay(calendar:JQuery, date:Date, currentView:FullCalendar.ViewObject) {
    if (currentView.name !== "agendaDay") {
        calendar.fullCalendar("changeView", "agendaDay");
    }
    calendar.fullCalendar("gotoDate", date);
}

onPageLoaded(){
    setTimeout(() => {
        var events: CalendarEvent[] = [
            new CalendarEvent(1, "Test Event 1", false, moment(new Date()), moment(new Date())),
            new CalendarEvent(2, "Test All Day Event 1", true, moment(new Date()), moment(new Date()))
        ];
        this.initiateCalendar(events);
    }, 2000);

    /*var me = this;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //window.setTimeout(function () {
            var events: CalendarEvent[] = [
                new CalendarEvent(1, "Test Event 1", false, moment(new Date()), moment(new Date())),
                new CalendarEvent(2, "Test All Day Event 1", true, moment(new Date()), moment(new Date()))
            ];
            me.initiateCalendar(events);
        //},200);
    });*/
}
```

}

I simply don't work and no errors are showed on console...
If I debug with Chrome developer tools I can see that 'calendar.fullCalendar' is null...

Apparently the fullcalendar.js is not being loaded... Someone can help?

Thanks!!

Comment: Didi you find a solution?

Comment: not yet..... =(